# How to know the number of names that start with each letter of a txt file using pyhton

Tags: python, list, file, tuples

I need to know how I can calculate the number of words in the list that start with the letter A, B, C .. Z.

Here I leave the reading part of the txt file

```py
#!/usr/bin/python


def main():
  lines = []
  xs = []

  try:
    with open("bin-nombres.txt", 'r') as fp:
      lines = [lines.strip() for lines in fp]

    for i in lines:
      print(i[0])
      xs = counterByLetter(i[0])

    print(xs)
  except EOFError as e:
    print(e)

  finally:
    pass

def counterByLetter(data):
  return [(k, v) for k, v in {v: data.count(v) for v in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'}.items()]  

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I must calculate the number of words that begin with [A ... Z]. For examples.

- There are 3 words that start with A.
- There are 20 words that start with B.
- etc..

Here I leave the solution to the problem. Thanking those who helped me !!

```py
import string


def main():
  try:
    # this initiates the counter with 0 for each letter
    letter_count = {letter: 0 for letter in list(string.ascii_lowercase)}
    with open("bin-nombres.txt", 'r') as fp:
      for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()
        initial = line[0].lower()
        letter_count[initial] += 1  # and here I increment per word


    #iterating over the dictionary to get the key and the value.
    #In the iteration process the values will be added to know the amount of words.
    size = 0
    for key , value in letter_count.items():
      size += value
      print("Names that start with the letter '{}' have {} numbers.".format(key , value))

    print("Total names in the file: {}".format(size))


  except EOFError as e:
    print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: It looks like your `main` should be a function, not a class.

Comment: upss yes, sorry

Comment: How's your file data like? What have you tried so far, other than reading the file's contents?

Comment: For now I'm experimenting with xs = list (filter (lambda x: x [0] == 'a', lines))

To see if later I can create a tuple so that I have something like that
('a', 4), ('b', 1)

Comment: As for txt, each line has only one word. Yes, it is already ordered by the alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, according to your updated answer (1 word per line, already alphabetically sorted), something like this should work:

```py
import string


def main():
  try:
    # this initiates our counter with 0 for each letter
    letter_count = {letter: 0 for letter in list(string.ascii_lowercase)}
    with open("words.txt", 'r') as fp:
      for line in fp:
        line = line.strip()
        initial = line[0].lower()
        letter_count[initial] += 1  # and here we increment per word

    print(letter_count)

  except EOFError as e:
    print(e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

**UPDATE:**

It's good that you don't just want a readymade solution, but your code has a few issues and some points are not super pythonic, that's why I suggested to do it as above. If you really want to go with your solution, you need to fix your `counterByLetter` function. The problem with it is that you're not actually storing the results anywhere, you're always returning a new array of results for each word. You probably have a word starting with 'z' as the last word of the file, hence the result having `0` as the count for all letters, except 'z', which has one. You need to update your values for the current letter in that function, instead of calculating the whole array at once.

Comment: Your solution works well!

But I would like to see if I can do it with my solution.

For now with my solution returns me

[('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0), ('d', 0), ('e', 0), ('f', 0), ( 'g', 0), ('h', 0), ('i', 0), ('j', 0), ('k', 0), ('l', 0), ('m ', 0), (' n ', 0), (' o ', 0), (' p ', 0), (' q ', 0), (' r ', 0), (' s', 0), ('t', 0), ('u', 0), ('v', 0), ('y', 0), ('x', 0), ('y', 0) , ('z', 1)]

Comment: @ChrisPerez I've updated my answer to talk a bit about ways to fix your code, then :)

Comment: @ChrisPerez Did any of the answers here help you reach your solution? If so, please mark one of them as the correct answer. If not, please let us know what's missing :)

Answer (score 1):

Assume that, there have a list name `list` which have 3 elements:

```
list = ["Geeks", "For", "Triks"]
```

And have a array which have 26 elements.

```
array = ["0", "0", ......"0", "0"......"0","0"]
```

`array[0]` represent the number of words start with `A`. 
..................
.................. 
`array[25]` represent the number of words start with `Z`. 
Then, 
if `list[n][0]` start with `A` then you need to increment `array[0]` by 1.

if `array[5] = 7` then it's mean that there are 7 words start with `F`. 
This is the straightforward logic for find the result.

Comment: You should always name your python variables with all-lowercase letters, so they're not confused with Classes, for instance.

Comment: Hi,

It shows me the following output:

[('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0), ('d', 0), ('e', 0), ('f', 0), ( 'g', 0), ('h', 0), ('i', 0), ('j', 0), ('k', 0), ('l', 0), ('m ', 0), (' n ', 0), (' o ', 0), (' p ', 0), (' q ', 0), (' r ', 0), (' s', 0), ('t', 0), ('u', 0), ('v', 0), ('y', 0), ('x', 0), ('y', 0) , ('z', 1)]

The values do not increase

Comment: Question is why ? for Z >> ('z', 1) .

Comment: @ShuvoKarmakar He shows me that tuple ('z', 1) because my solution was not working quite well.

But I already managed to solve the problem using the following:
k = {letter: 0 for letter in list (string.ascii_lowercase)}

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to change a bit your code like this.

Use [**collection.defaultdic**t](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) set to [**int**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#int) as value: using the first letter as key of the [**dictionary**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) you are able to increment its value each there is a match. So:

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

Set `xs` as `xs = defaultdict(int)`

Change the `for i in lines:` body to

```
for i in lines:
  xs[i[0]] += 1
```

If you print `xs` at the end of the `for` loop you'll get something like:

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'P': 3, 'G': 2, 'R': 2})
```

Keys in dict are case sensitive, so, take care of transforming the case, if required.

You don't need an external method to do the counting job.

Comment: Thanks Bro!! very easy explanation